# In jsf, how should a bean communicate with a regular java class (aka the business logic)

Tags: jsf, netbeans, glassfish, javabeans, facelets

This is a jsf project on glassfish, developed with Netbeans. I try to connect my beans to my regular java classes.

Here is what I understand:
- Managed beans or their CDI equivalent take care of the UI-related user data (eg, user input)
- The business logic is implemented in regular java classes
- 2 Managed beans or their CDI equivalent can commmunicate with @injection

What I am missing is: how do beans communicate with *regular java classes*? (where my business logic is?)
 In other word, I wish I couldrun my java classes by using the beans as arguments to their constructor!

I tried:
- including a @Inject annotation in my java classes, but that does not work (the bean is not injected, remains null)
like

```
public class myJavaProgram (){
@Inject
UserInputBean userInputBean;
//my business logic using the properties of userInputBean here...  //does not work, userInputBean is null!
}
```

- passing the properties of the bean as arguments in the constructor of my java class. Works, but ugly: why can't I simply pass the whole bean directly as an argument to the constructor? But when I do that I get again a null pointer exception on the bean in my java class.
  Am I missing something? Thx!

Comment: A very open ended question, more detail would help. But anyway, in our applications, we turn it around. We have action handler classes that the commandButtons delegate to and those classes either instantiate business objects directly, or have business objects injected into them. In other words, make your business objects clients of your action handlers rather than try to use beans as clients of your business objects.

Comment: My pb is very simple: my bean collects 2 strings from the user input: first name and last name. I'd like to export these two strings into a class which does an API call taking these two strings as parameters. Your solution is interesting but I am surprised there is not a more straightforward way to deal with that? Thx anyway @SteveAtkinson

Comment: I don't understand, you need something like `public class Bean { String s1; String s2; public void someAction() { BL bl = new BL(); bl.doSomething(s1, s2); //...} }` and then in your page use `<h:commandButton value="click me" action="#{bean.someAction}" />`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I don't think the OP really knows what his problem is, he just seems fundamentally confused about the concept of dependency injection and inversion of control frameworks.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks that's very simple and useful indeed. You would not believe this very simple "pattern" is not provided anywhere. maple_shaft, I know very precisely what my problem is (as stated in 3 lines in my comment), and that's why I come for answers here.

Comment: It's just basic Java. Are you new to Java or so? Based on your question history, I'd warmly recommend picking a decent Java and Java EE book.

Comment: @BalusC. This is my own limitation then (I am fully equipped in Java / JSF books - good ones). In basic Java, objects can be passed in constructors. Beans being sorts of objects, I thought they could be passed as args to a Java class. But no, oh, well! :-) I understand the solutions and that is fine, thanks to everyone for their help.

Comment: calling `BL bl = new BL(); bl.doSomething(s1, s2);` a pattern is stretching it a bit, as BalusC said, it' just basic java. You could also have a constructor in you bl that takes the bean as an object reference `public class BL { BL(MyBean bean) { } }` and in your acton handler, `someAction() { new BL(this); }` but that would be bad idea anyway as it tightly couples your presentation bean to your BL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern enterprise applications usually use the dependency injection pattern throughout the entire application, not just the presentation layer. So you'd have a data access layer contributing beans such as `EntityManager`. These are injected into business services, that form the business service layer. The business services, in turn, are injected into your JSF backing beans. What dependency injection container is best is a matter of debate, you can also mix them.

In the Java EE 6 standard (at least how I read it), EJB acts as dependency injection container for the data access and the business service layer, and CDI as dependency injection container for the presentation layer (that's why you can inject EJBs in CDI beans). Others want to replace EJB and use CDI through all layers. Yet others still smart from the hurt J2EE inflicted, and use Spring as dependency injection container.

To give a little code, you might do:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean {

    @Inject UserService userService;

    User user;

    public void save() {
        userService.create(user);
    }

}

@Stateless
public class UserService {
    public void create(User user) { ... }
}
```

Comment: >EJB acts as dependency injection container for the data access and the business service layer - I wouldn't exactly put it like that. CDI is the overall injection facility. There happens to be injection offered in EJB beans (@Resource, @EJB), but this is considered superseded by CDI. EJB indeed does offer services that are particularly handy for data access and the business layer (but it's expected these too will become CDI based services eventually)

Comment: As far as I know, neither the JEE 6 spec nor the JEE 7 spec makes a recommendation for or against the use of CDI in the data access and business service layers. While I agree that it is likely that @EJB will be deprecated in future versions of the JEE spec, that hasn't happened yet, and is therefore a matter of opinion.

Comment: Indeed, the specs don't specifically say something about CDI being suitable or not for that. Although this wasn't what I exactly meant ;) I was just referring to the injection capabilities, e.g. `@Inject` vs `@Resource`. In EJB beans you can use `@Inject` for many things (not all!) and thus let CDI handle the injection, while still using the EJB component model and EJB services (like pooling, security, and so on).

Comment: >While I agree that it is likely that @EJB will be deprecated in future versions of the JEE spec, that hasn't happened yet - It indeed hasn't happened yet, but it's actually being discussed. See e.g. the comment from the EJB spec lead (Marina) on her blog: https://blogs.oracle.com/marina/entry/ejb_3_2_news (last comment)

Comment: >and is therefore a matter of opinion - Well, for the time being I think EJB are the better beans for data access/business logic. By far not all EJB services have been migrated to CDI extensions/interceptors. So for data access and business logic I would personally recommend to keep using EJB. But as said, EJB can be enriched with CDI, using `@Inject` where possible to inject EJB beans into other beans and applying CDI scopes to EJB beans where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that when you say CGI that you in fact mean CDI...

This is an IoC (Inversion of Control) framework to facilitate DI (Dependency Injection) in your JSF application.  Another example of such a framework would be Spring, which is slowly beginning to adopt better JSF support.

If you intend on seperating business logic from the managed beans into CDI injected beans, then the role of the JSF managed bean is that of a View Controller and repository for your Presentation Logic.

The `@Inject` annotation will only inject objects that have been configured through CDI, which depending on your project setup may or may not actually include JSF Managed Beans.  This all depends on how you configured the project and what EL Resolver implementation is in use.  If it is the default EL Resolver for your JSF implementation (Eg. Mojarra) then the JSF implementation of the EL Resolver is being utilized and your IoC will not recognize these dependencies.

You can of course still do dependency injection of managed beans into other managed beans but you will need to do this through the EL Resolver.

```
@ManagedProperty("#{userInputBean}")
UserInputBean userInputBean;
```

Other Java class dependencies that you refer to should represent your Business Logic layer and should be configured by and handled through CDI.